# Booting from a USB

Tags: operating-systems, fedora

I have a kickstart USB that can install Fedora 12 (yes I know it is old, but I am running a test).

Is it possible for me to insert my USB stick, and boot from it to install that operating system on my Raspberry Pi?

If not, is there a way around this?

Comment: No the Pi has to boot off the SD card, The rest of the OS except the boot files can be run off a USB drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, the RPI firmware only boots from the local physical SD card. The USB is invisible during the boot process.

Take a look at this [answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/757/boot-from-usb-hard-disk/41201#41201), also check the 'boot' section on [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39959/raspian-boot-process-and-the-partition-table/39969#39969).

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to boot a Pi is from the SD card.