# How can I install GRUB2 on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-4, kernel, ubuntu, bootloader

With a Raspberry Pi 4, I would like to run Ubuntu and GRUB2. [This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99473/why-is-grub-incompatible-with-the-raspberry-pi/99558#99558) says that GRUB is a prerequisite for the generic Linux kernel, but does not explain how to install it.

Comment: You can't because a RPi doesn't boot that way. If you want Ubuntu you need the RPi specific version from https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Comment: @Dougie Is that specifically for the Pi 4? The page [linked in the official Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Generic_kernel_with_grub2) describes setting up GRUB on a Pi 3.

Comment: GRUB is irrelevant. Raspberry Pis don't have a BIOS, they don't use UEFI so there's nothing for GRUB to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to multi-boot then use [Berryboot from here](https://berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot)  - I've not seen Grub on a Pi :-)

Ubuntu has its own images for [the server version](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) - you could build a GUI version from that if you wanted...