# How can I enter Ubuntu desktop recovery mode?

Tags: ubuntu, gui, lightdm, gdm

I removed gdm and install lightdm, after that I am stuck at infinite loading.

[image]

Pressed Ctrl + Alt + F2, unable to use TTY...
And I cannot enter recovery mode by press shift...
What can I do for it?

Answer (score 1):

Using another computer, edit your cmdline.txt file and append the following:

```
init=/bin/bash
```

This will skip the init process and drop you to a root shell.  If `bash` isn't installed on your distro, then try `/bin/sh`.

Once you're done making changes, make sure you run `sync` to flush the write cache, then power off the Pi and revert the changes to cmdline.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall the system and write down the password.

Answer (score -1):

There is no desktop rescue mode in Linux.

In a *regular Debian or Ubuntu* you instead have to start the rescue mode from the GRUB menu.

However, the Raspberry Pi installations [don't use GRUB by default](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99473). So the other option is to [boot on *an install disk* (i.e. a USB thumb drive)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md) and use the rescue menu option from there.

There are plenty of posts about how to use that mode so I won't go in detail here about that. More or less, you'll be able to reinstall a working package or tweak the settings of the existing package to *possibly* make it work. That mode includes a way to start a shell in a terminal, which you can use to tweak your settings directly in files and install/remove packages.

Comment: Does this apply to the Raspberry Pi (which AFAIK) doesn't use Grub to boot and instead boots from an SD card by default?

Comment: Ah, indeed. Although [it can be installed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99473), it's not by default.