# Run a RaspbianOS system for rpi4 on rpi3b?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, pi-3b+

I have an OpenHab 3.1 installation on a raspberry 4 running. I'm currently using [raspiBackup](https://github.com/framps/raspiBackup) to create a full backup of the system and also having an .img file to restore it when needed via Etcher under Windows.

Now I wanted to give the restore a try and boot it from a raspberry 3b. But all I get is a black screen. I checked the `/boot` directory and it seems `bootcode.bin` and `start.elf` are missing on the origin system. Adding them manually from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot) to the restored boot partition shows still a black screen, but at least the green ACT led is blinking 4 times - which basically means it has issues loading the `start.elf` - as far as I understood it.

My actual question is now, is it even possible to run a RasbianOS installed on a rpi4 on a rpi3b?
I'm booting from a SSD directly connected via the same SATA2USB adapter - in both cases. If I do a fresh RasbianOS install using the rpi3b, it boots properly.

Comment: This Question is hopelessly confused and what you appear to be asking has nothing to do with the title.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there was not much help coming from here what to check/try to come closer to the root cause (especially for the black screen), I want to give my findings back so someone else might find it useful.

To make it short: it is possible.

I had to use serial debugging though to find out, why there wasn't even the rainbow block showing up - but just a black screen. It gave the necessary hints why it wasn't booting.

First, my rpi4 image was trimmed down during installation of Openhab to just support the rpi4 as it seems. So e.g. required files for the rpi3b like `bootcode.bin`, `start.elf` and `kernel.img`/`kernel7.img` were missing on `/boot`. But just copying them over from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot) didn't work. Serial debugging showed, it was failing on `.dtb` files and after replacing them also overlay files. So I just replaced all files in `/boot` with the raspberry Github repo `boot` in the end.

Another issue was, that I had set `gpu_mem=16` in the rpi4 image `config.txt` that the rpi3b didn't like. Sadly there was no indication - even with serial debugging about this. It was just stopping after initializing the uart stuff. Take-away from this is, doublecheck your `cmdline.txt` and `config.txt` for maybe "harmful" settings that might not be supported by the rpi model you're trying to boot from. Try to comment them out and see if it boots further or not.

It can also be helpful to understand the [boot process](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10595/121055) in general and [what are the files in `/boot` used for](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#the-boot-folder).

After adapting those things, the rpi4 image was booting properly on a rpi3b (with USB boot already enabled).

Answer (score 0):

You can run Raspberry Pi OS (32bit) on any model Pi.

Whether you can boot from a SSD depends.

Comment: The actual question is, if an installed pi4 system can simply boot by replacing the pi4 with a pi3b. For me this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I understand that the last part (boot from an SSD) is exactly the case the OP is having. It would be good to know on what it depends.