# Where is the boot sequence documented in detail?

Tags: pi-4, boot, bootloader, bare-metal

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.rpi4os.com/) on writing "bare metal" code for the Raspberry Pi 4. I've gotten the code working fine, but I'm left wondering how I could have figured any of this stuff out for my own. The basic process I'm following is to compile my code into a file called `kernel8.img`, put that on an SD card formatted in a certain way with a bunch of other files, and then plug that in and power on the Pi.

Where is the documentation that would tell me to do all this? I found [this](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#second-stage-bootloader), which is a good start, but when it comes to how it loads data off the SD card it just says:

```
else if boot-mode == SD CARD

    Attempt to load firmware from the SD card

        Success - run the firmware

        Failure - continue
```

Clearly a lot is being left out - there's no mention of the need to name a file `kernel8.img`, no mention that the SD card needs to be formatted in fat32 (or at least the card I bought is), what flags need to be set on the partition, etc.

Where can I find actual detailed documentation on the boot sequence, and what protocols I need to follow to run my code on a Pi 4?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10442/what-is-the-boot-sequence) and the 2nd more recent answer which has a link for updated boot information for the PI 4.