# How can I enable wireless for a dropbear-initramfs

Tags: wifi, boot, wireless, encryption

I'm trying to unlock cryptdisks over wifi+ssh. It's fairly common to have luks disks + ssh, but I've never seen a tutorial geared towards wifi.

In fact, if you run `update-initramfs -u -v -k $(uname -r)` as suggested in [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92558/133489) and every other post essentially, the script explicitly lists `wireless` and a bunch of similar  sounding kernel modules as *excluded*. I have gone about the business of editing out those exclusions, and also trying [these patches](http://www.marcfargas.com/posts/enable-wireless-debian-initramfs/index.html)

Nothing seems to work. On boot, the pi is not visible on the network (`interface wlan0 not found` is commonly shown), and dropbear-initramfs never seems to "answer". `nmap` never shows the device or port.

Rather than debug my particular setup (which I  would appreciate)...

**is there a canonical way to have dropbear-initramfs pick up over a wifi network so that I can retreive keyfiles or ssh in before cryptsetup asks for passwords**

I'm on a PI-zero-w or 4b with latest raspbian

Comment: I'm also interested in this, but haven't manage to achieve anything so far. Have you found a way ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?
https://gist.github.com/telenieko/d17544fc7e4b347beffa87252393384c

Haven't tried it yet, was just googling the question because I'm thinking of trying it out and while doing so I stumbled upon your question and the gist I've linked above.

Also there's a gentoo forum thread about the topic there:
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1040452-start-0.html

Comment: Please post the relevant details from those sources here.  Answers consisting only of links are not particularly helpful and are liable to be deleted.